# Add Relationship when adding new Contact in Wordpress

Tags: relationships

I am using the Related Permissions Module to limit Contacts (club members) when an admin, for 1 of 52 clubs, logs in. Admins login to a backend at this point, still trying to create custom Dashboard for frontend that allows creation of new Contacts. All the admin sees is the Contacts with a Relationship to that club. I need the club admin to be able to add the Relationship when adding a new Contact. Without being able to add the Relationship at the time the new Contact is created, the club admin cannot see the new Contact after it is saved. Is there a way to include 'Add Relationship' on the new Contact form?

Comment: I think you will need to explore the short-lived Caldera form integration to get this running until Ninja forms takes its place

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach might be to use CiviRules to automatically create the relationship based on some criteria.

As Pete points out, building your form using Caldera Forms would give you the functionality you want, but has an end-of-life of December 31st 2021.  Form Builder may be able to handle this too, I haven't checked recently.